# Magento Grunt Less Compilation behaves weird

Tags: magento2, less, theme-fallback, grunt

I have a custom theme `Mycompany/mytheme` including `<Magento>/<blank>` as parent.

The locale is set to de_DE.

When I execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE` everything works fine, my `custom-m.less` and `custom-l.less` get compiled into `custom-m.css` and `custom-l.css` and I also get the Magento/blank theme files and viewing the magento website with chrome also loads these files.

custom-m.less and custom-l.less are exact copies from the blank themes styles-m and styles-l less files

---

**The Problem:**

Using `grunt exec:mytheme` and `grunt less:mytheme` kinda behaves strange. I still load the Magento/blank styles-l.css but everything else gets loaded via their own less component files (e.g. _extend.less or _module.less)
[image]

---

Here is my grunt config file:

magento-root/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

```
module.exports = {

    -----------------------------
    ... blank and luma stuff here
    -----------------------------

    mytheme: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Mycompany/mytheme',
        locale: 'de_DE',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/email',
            'css/email-inline',
            'css/custom-m',
            'css/custom-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },

    --------------------------
    ... backend stuff here ...
    --------------------------

};
```

'css/styles-m', 'css/styles-l', 'css/email', 'css/email-inline' are not inside my mytheme, but as magento devdocs says should anyways be included because of the parent theme inheriting. I also tried to not include these files inside the config file = Same result

**BTW:** grunt commands throw no errors, seems to work fine, in var/view_preprocessed I see my custom files inside the Mycompany/mytheme folders, same as pub/static/frontend....

I deleted the cache after each new try

Server-side compilation enabled

developer mode enabled

---

**Question:**  Can someone help me with this? Can someone explain whats wrong?

And what is the expected workflow? Magento Documentation is a bit unclear about that

1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -> grunt watch ?
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -> grunt exec:mytheme -> grunt watch ?
3. grunt exec:mytheme -> grunt watch ?

Should I use the magento php compiler at all? Because I don't want to, way too slow

Comment: There is two types of compilation in magento, you can compile via grunt or server side compilation. Which type are you used for it ?

Comment: as I described, using server-side compilation using `php bin/magento setup:static-content deploy` works fine. When I use grunt I get this strange behavior, as described above

Answer (score 0):

You need use Grunt for display source code inspecting in firebug and you have explain how it works.

[Magento 2 - How to configure Grunt in PhpStorm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112363/magento-2-how-to-configure-grunt-in-phpstorm/120036#120036)

Comment: [@juhanix](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/44070/juhanix) Helped you with my answer?