# Css path of magento

Tags: magento2, css

I created custom theme and I overrided **Magento_catalog** and css of parent from folder Magento_catalog in blank theme. now I want to change some css code like gallery.I use firebug in chrome to find **path** and line **css** of gallery,but it shows me style.css in pub folder.how can I find exactly path of css??

thanks!

Comment: did you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command ?

Comment: Did you try my solution ?

Comment: @Pawan thanks for helping but your solution wasn't  exactly related to my question..

Comment: Welcome but I think its related , you want to overide default CSS and you can do it by custom css.

Comment: @Pawan my problem is I cant find the path of css parent theme.I confuse about  the element that I want to change it, be in which folder of css ?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS files for Magento 2 are generated from several `less` files. When you run your webshop in developer mode (on your local machine), and then running the grunt commands (I usually run `grunt exec:<theme> && grunt less:<theme> && grunt watch:<theme>`), your browser will show the `less` file that contains the styling of the selected element.

If this isn't working for you, it could also help by finding a specific piece of styling, like the class, can be tracked back to one or more `less` files in your installation. This will most likely make it possible to track back where the original styling is declared. Be aware, this can also be in the parent theme (could be the blank theme).

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Grunt processor.
Your answer, it finds in below link:

[Magento 2 - How to configure Grunt in PhpStorm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112363/magento-2-how-to-configure-grunt-in-phpstorm/120036#120036)

Comment: what do I with grunt?I don t fully understand about grunt

Comment: @mrs.programmer If you use Grunt it makes you a map of all created styles and shows you in **Inspect Element** in which `.less` file and at what line is the stylize you are tilting